# Reference for Grothendieck's theorem on representation of unramified functors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, representable-functors, algebraic-spaces

In the Exposé 294 of the Bourbaki Seminar of the year 1964-1965, Murre gives an outline of proof of a theorem of Grothendieck giving necessary and sufficient conditions of representability by a scheme for a functor which is unramified and separated. This is very interesting because it is probably the first general representability theorem that did not use projective methods: a precursor to Artin's representability theorems.

I am wondering if there exists a more complete and cleaned-up treatment somewhere in the literature, with full proofs. This would be nice for at least two reasons:

1. The outline of Murre is very sketchy at times, and some details would be very welcome.
2. There are some complements and generalizations of the theorem whose proof is lacking. For instance, after the statement of the main theorem there is a Note saying « it is possible to prove a statement similar to theorem 1 with "unramified" replaced by "locally quasi-finite" over S. »

Does anyone know such a treatment ?

Comment: I agree that this result would benefit from being reformulated using algebraic spaces. Eg show representability by algebraic spaces using Artin's criterion, and then use the fact that a quasi-finite separated morphism of aglebraic spaces is representable by schemes. I feel the same about  Raynaud's, Un critère d’effectivité de descente, Th 4.1

Comment: Right! On the other hand, the specific situation of unramified functors allows to simplify a lot the deformation-theoretic arguments, which is what Grothendieck does (and is the reason why he was able to find an "Artin criteria" theorem before algebraic spaces where discovered). This makes this result interesting.

Comment: Well formal versality is rather easy to check using Schlessinger's criterion. Then you need algebraicity (for effectivity). Artin's approximation is a big theorem, but can be used as a black box. In practice the hard part to check is openness of versality. But for a smooth alg space (over the base), this is a lot easier to check (no obstruction to deformations). In particular this apply in the étale case. Now an unramified morphism is étale locally a closed immersion. So essentially you just need the étale case of Artin's axioms, and then use representability of loc. qf separated morphisms.

Comment: So I think we mostly agree that unramified functors simplify the deformation-theoretic arguments, but my point of view is that more generally the smooth case simplify deformation-theoretic arguments. To get the unramified case we just need the fact that a sheaf which is étale locally an algebraic space is algebraic.